# Android internal storage not saving file

Tags: android, android-context, internal-storage

I have a main activity, and when pressing on a listItem, It launches a new activity by an intent. This new activity's **theme is Dialog** (so it looks like the second activity is floating over the main activity).

In this new activity I enter some data in EditTexts, then with that data I create a custom object, and try to save it in internal storage.

it seems it isn't creating the file. I can't really understand why it isn't working, as I am using the same structure with other objects in other activities and it's working properly. This is what makes me think that it must have something to do with the fact that this activity's **theme is Dialog**. The custom object class obviously implements Serializable, and I have all the permissions in my android manifest. Maybe the problem is related to **the context I'm passing** to the saving method(`getApplicationContext()`).

**This is the Activity with the Dialog theme:**

```
package es.lagoacunado.lagoacunadoconsutores;

import java.io.File;

import utilidades.SeriaPreferencias;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import clases.Preferencia;

public class Preferencias extends Activity {

    EditText ftpDir, ftpUser, ftpPass;
    Button btnGuardar, btnCancelar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preferencias);

        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

        ftpDir = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ftpDIR);
        ftpUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ftpUSER);
        ftpPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ftpPASS);
        btnGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);
        btnCancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);

        File filePref = new File("preferencias.dat");
        if (filePref.exists()) {
            /*
             * ftpDir.setText(SeriaPreferencias.cargarPreferencias(
             * getApplicationContext()).getDirFTP());
             * ftpUser.setText(SeriaPreferencias.cargarPreferencias(
             * getApplicationContext()).getUsrFTP());
             * ftpPass.setText(SeriaPreferencias.cargarPreferencias(
             * getApplicationContext()).getPssFTP());
             */
            Preferencia loadPref = SeriaPreferencias
                    .cargarPreferencias(getApplicationContext());
            ftpDir.setText(loadPref.getDirFTP());
            ftpUser.setText(loadPref.getUsrFTP());
            ftpPass.setText(loadPref.getPssFTP());
        }

        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String dir, usr, pss;
                dir = ftpDir.getText().toString();
                usr = ftpUser.getText().toString();
                pss = ftpPass.getText().toString();

                //Log.d("PRUEBA Guardar Preferencias", "dir= "+dir+" -- user= "+usr+" -- pss= "+pss);

                Preferencia pref = new Preferencia(dir, usr, pss);
                // METHOD THAT SAVES THE OBJECT pref
                SeriaPreferencias.guardarPreferencias(getApplicationContext(),
                        pref);

                File prueba = new File("preferencias.dat");
                if(prueba.exists()){
                    Log.d("-->PRUEBA", "EL ARCHIVO EXISTE");
                }

                finish();
            }
        });

        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**This is the class with the saving and loading methods:**

```
package utilidades;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import clases.Preferencia;

public class SeriaPreferencias {

    private static String FICHERO = "preferencias.dat";

    public static void guardarPreferencias(Context context, Preferencia prefs) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FICHERO,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(prefs);

            oos.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MiCV", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Preferencia cargarPreferencias(Context context) {
        Preferencia prefs = null;

        try {

            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(FICHERO);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            prefs = (Preferencia) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MiCV", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return prefs;
    }

}
```

**and this is the custom object class:**

```
package clases;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Preferencia implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String dirFTP, usrFTP, pssFTP;

    public Preferencia() {

    }

    public Preferencia(String dirFTP, String usrFTP, String pssFTP) {
        this.dirFTP = dirFTP;
        this.usrFTP = usrFTP;
        this.pssFTP = pssFTP;
    }

    public String getDirFTP() {
        return dirFTP;
    }

    public void setDirFTP(String dirFTP) {
        this.dirFTP = dirFTP;
    }

    public String getUsrFTP() {
        return usrFTP;
    }

    public void setUsrFTP(String usrFTP) {
        this.usrFTP = usrFTP;
    }

    public String getPssFTP() {
        return pssFTP;
    }

    public void setPssFTP(String pssFTP) {
        this.pssFTP = pssFTP;
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you determining that the file is not being saved?  What if anything do you see in your log?  Anything from your catch blocks?  How about putting in messages which give partial progress reports as it tries to save, tell you where the file has been created, etc.

Comment: because i have this IF sentence right after the saving method, and if the file exists it must show a log.d confirming it.`File prueba = new File("preferencias.dat");
                if(prueba.exists()){
                    Log.d("-->PRUEBA", "EL ARCHIVO EXISTE");
                }`

Comment: the problem must be in the saving method `SeriaPreferencias.guardarPreferencias(getApplicationContext(), pref);`, or in the Context I'm passing to this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 File filePref = new File("preferencias.dat");
```

Specifying only a filename and no directory will refer to a file in the current working directory - but this is quite likely the filesystem root directory which is not only an inappropriate place, but not writable by your application.

When you use Context.openFileOuput(filename) to open or create a FileOutputStream, the filename refers to a location in your app's private directory of the internal storage.

To create a file Object pointing towards that same file in private storage area of your application, **from within an Activity class or other valid Context, during or subsequent to its onCreate() method** you can use:

```
File filePref = new File(getFilesDir(), "preferencias.dat");
```

Because Context.getFilesDir() refers to the same private folder location as Context.openFileOutput() uses.

Comment: I'm not using the File() constructor to create the file. The file is created by the `SeriaPreferencias.guardarPreferencias()`. I'm using the file constructor to CHECK if the file exists. And I don't agree with the second part of your answer. As I said in my question, I'm already using the same structure to save files in internal storage AND IT WORKS, so once again, the problem must be the context I'm passing because of being Dialog the theme set to this activity.

Comment: If you have an invalid context, you should see a message from your log statement or something from a system Exception handler. And no, you aren't by any appearances running the existence check after your save method - you are calling it in the onCreate() of your activity.  Plus the issue with the failure to provide a valid path to the File() constructor used for the existence check needs to be addressed.

Comment: nope, the one in the onCreate() is to check if the file already exists, and if it does, then load the data contained in the file into the EditTexts. If you continue reading the code, you will see a OnClickListener, and there it is where I am calling the saving method.

Comment: You are still misusing the File() constructor with an invalid path.

Comment: why is the -1 for? I'm not misusing the file() constructor, as I'm telling you it works in other similar cases, and the only difference between this case and the others is the Dialog theme.

Comment: Post the output of logging filePref.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: it says `/preferencias.dat`

Comment: Yes, just as I've been telling you for some time now, **that is not a path you can write to**, which comes about from **misusing the constructor**.  Obtain a valid path and use the two-argument constructor as shown in this answer.  Context.getFilesDir() is documented to obtain the location used by Context.openFileOutput()

Comment: but I create the file using `FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`. isn't that the method used for internal storaging?

Comment: Sure, you create it reasonably.  But when you try to check for it, you check for it in the root directory of the phone, not in your app's private directory where you created it.  Stop misusing the File() constructor - pass it the actual directory as well as the filename, and then you will be able to check if the file actually exists in that plausible location.

Comment: You're absolutely right. could I be mixing it with java? because in java I create the files in the same directory where the .jar file is, so maybe I mixed all up. Plus maybe talking in English may confuse me sometimes. Thanks a lot. PS: could you remove the -1? just wondering...